# Strategy for p:fileDownload with dialog and loading status

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

Strategy for [`p:fileDownload`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileDownload.jsf) with dialog with loading

I am trying to make a loading bar after starting the download of a file. My download button is like this:

```
<p:commandButton id="btnFirstType"
            styleClass="bt_princ"
             value="Download File"
             onclick="loading.show()"
             ajax="false">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{mbean.myFile}"/>
</p:commandButton>

<p:dialog modal="true" 
          widgetVar="loading" 
          header="Status"   
          draggable="false" 
          closable="false">  
        <p:graphicImage value="/loading.gif" />  
</p:dialog>
```

And my MBean is like this:

```
public StreamedContent getMyFile(){
     return this.getReport(Type.CSV); //I assure this works, debugged...
}
```

The problem is, after clicking the download button, if I start the loading dialog, the download doesn't occurr. 
I thought about using [`p:poll`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/poll.jsf) to check a boolean variable so I know when the file has been generated, so I could show the dialog after clicking the button (like setting `setTimeout` with JavaScript), but this is maybe my mistake about how the whole thing happens. Any other suggestion?

PS1: Polling stops working after the file is downloaded, so I won't know when to close the dialod

PS2: I am using Primefaces 2.2 and can't update.

PS3: Found [this](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1616) workaround but 'it will' be on version 3, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same as suggested in the workaround posted on my question.
I downloaded the primefaces sources from my version, changed the FileDownloadActionListener class, added cookies in the response object and in my page I just started a process with setTimeout that would check cookies every 100 miliseconds, and when find it, delete it.